# Is there a more efficient way to find belongs_to records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Given these models:

```
Class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end
```

and

```
Class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

The only way I can think of right now is:

```
dev_list = []
locations = Location.near("some address") # using Geocoder :)
locations.each do |loc|
  dev_list += loc.devices
end
```

Is there a more efficient way than that .each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have thought about this a bit more before asking but the answer is fairly simple:

```
locations = Location.near("some address") # using Geocoder :)
location_ids = locations.map{|loc| loc.id}.join(',') # creates string of Location ids: "1,3,5,6,7,12,..."
dev_list = Device.where("location_id IN (#{location_ids})")
```

Tested against a list of 1000 Locations. The `.each` loop took around 11 seconds (wall clock), this way was almost instantaneous.

Note that in the `Device.where` statement I use `#{location_ids}` rather than the more secure `["location_id IN (?)", location_ids]`. This is because using the array condition statement would result in the following SQL (at least for MySQL):

```
SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE (location_id in ('5565,5098,2293'))
```

which only finds devices for which the location_id is 5565.